# Laravel 7 $.ajax request not executed

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to add comments to a post using ajax and laravel7
At the bottom of the post show blade template i include this part to display existing comments and a form to add a new one

```
<div class="container comments" #id="commentaires">
    <h2 class="comments-title">Commentaires des adhérents</h2>
    
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        <div class="comment-header">
            Posté par
            {!! \App\User::find($comment->agent_id)->firstname; !!}
            {!! \App\User::find($comment->agent_id)->familyname; !!}
            
            le
            <?php \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('fr');?>
            {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($comment->created_at)->translatedFormat('l jS F Y')}}
        </div>
        <div class="comment-body">
            {{$comment->content}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
    @auth
        <div class="comment-form">
            <div class="comment-invite">
                Laissez un commentaire
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(['action'=>"CommentController@store",'method'=>'POST']) !!}
                <div class="row post-option-background">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        {{ Form::hidden('post_id', $post->id) }}
                        {{ Form::hidden('agent_id', auth()->user()->id) }}
                         {{ Form::text('content','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{Form::submit('Enregistrer',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-submit'])}}

            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
    @endauth
    @guest
        <div class="comment-invite">
            Connectez-vous pour laisser un commentaire
        </div>
    @endguest
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    });

    $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_id = $("input[name=post_id]").val();
        var agent_id = $("input[name=agent_id]").val();
        var content = $("input[name=content]").val();
        console.log('post_id is : '+post_id+', agent_id is : '+agent_id+' and content is : '+content);
        var url='{{ url('comments') }}'
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:url,
            data:{post_id:post_id, agent_id:agent_id, content:content},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                 $("#commentaires").append("<div> success </div>");
                 console.log('success');}
        });
        console.log('reaching end of click function');
    });
</script>
```

ROUTES

My routes are

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
Route::post('/comments','CommentController@store')->name('storeAjax');
```

My store function in CommentController is

```
/**
 * Store a newly created comment in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request){
    if ($request->ajax()){
        $this->validate($request, [
        'content'=>'required',
        'post_id'=>'required',
        'agent_id'=>'required'
        ]);
            return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
    } else{
        return 'request is not ajax';
    }
}
```

I display the post, fill the comment form with : 'This is an example' and click submit button.

The click function is executed and I can see the various messages in the console

> post_id is : 131, agent_id is : 1 and content is : This is an example
> 131:303:21 http://localhost:8000/comments 131:305:12 reaching end of
> click function

Nevertheless, nothing happens in the browser. It seems that the ajax request is not executed.
Can somebody help me fixing this ?

Comment: Wrap your script in jQuery's [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Go in the 'network' section of your browser developer tools to see and debug the request you are making, it probably gives you an error (so the `success` callback is not executed)

Comment: Ready wrap fixed it. Thank you @DigitalDrifter

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).on('button.btn-submit','click',function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
//rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be [Laravel's CSRF protection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf). You can confirm this by looking in the Network panel of your browser's dev tools (e.g. [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) or [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference)). If submitting the form creates a new entry with status `419` then it's a CSRF problem.

You need to add the CSRF token to your HTML (usually in a `meta` tag) and send that token with your POST request.

Add this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Add this to your main JS file (e.g. `bootstrap.js`)

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

If that doesn't fix it have a look in the Laravel error log.

Comment: It is already in the script. Should I absolutely put it in the main file ?

Comment: The important thing is that it runs before any jQuery ajax call. I always put it in bootstrap.js to ensure that.